# Can't change text on hololens

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I just started using a Hololens and have been messing around with the voice recognition scripts from the tutorials on the Microsoft website.I have been using unity to create 3D texts, however, if I try to change the text using voice commands it does not work!

This is my following code  :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Windows.Speech;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class VoiceRecognized : MonoBehaviour {
KeywordRecognizer kr = null;
Dictionary<string, System.Action> keywords = new Dictionary<string, System.Action>();

// Use this for initialization
public Text name_text;

private string testName = "Drop";
void begin () {

    keywords.Add("Change", () =>
    {
        this.BroadcastMessage("OnReset");

    });

    kr = new KeywordRecognizer(keywords.Keys.ToArray());

    kr.OnPhraseRecognized += KeywordRecognizer_OnPhraseRecognized;
    kr.Start();
}
public void KeywordRecognizer_OnPhraseRecognized(PhraseRecognizedEventArgs args)
{
    System.Action keywordAction;
    if (keywords.TryGetValue(args.text, out keywordAction))
    {
        keywordAction.Invoke();
    }
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
}
}
```

The other program that changes the text upon hearing "Change".

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeText : MonoBehaviour {
public Text name_text;


void Start()
{

}
void OnReset()
{

    name_text.text = "Change"; 
}
}
```

In this code, I am using voice recognition script to change the initial text "Hello World" to "Change". I am not sure if there a problem with my Unity, however I am currently following everything Microsoft is doing with their tutorials.

Comment: 1) are you sure the voice command is being recognized?  2) is the `ChangeText` class located on the same object as the `voiceRecognized` class?

Comment: thanks! It wasn't in the change text class

Comment: Where is begin method called?

Comment: Have you checked if you were able to reference your text game object in the `ChangeText` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try invoking same method on button click, see if that works. You can use Debug.Log to see if you method gets called with voice command.